# How to convert string like 1.424304064E9 to datetime in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

My data is in this format - "1.424304064E9"

I have tried pandas.to_datetime(df['ts']) but no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: May i know what date you expecting?

Comment: @saimadhu.polamuri: Obviously any date in the year 1424304064 AD is sufficient; by that point, nobody bothers with months anymore, they're like pennies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply it on a full column, you can also do:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'s':["1.424304064E9", "1.424304064E9"]})

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
               s
0  1.424304064E9
1  1.424304064E9

In [9]: pd.to_datetime(df['s'].astype(float), unit='s')
Out[9]:
0   2015-02-19 00:01:04
1   2015-02-19 00:01:04
Name: s, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float("1.424304064E9"))`